# Do I need to repay back my line of credit in the form of monthly payments?

Tags: canada, banking, credit, financial-literacy, line-of-credit

When I take a line of credit, do I start making monthly payments, like with a mortgage? Or do I make a lump sum (principal + interest) payment at the end of the term of the line of credit? Or is there no term at all, and I can pay back the principal and interest at a much, much later date?

Comment: Did you read your loan agreement? It must be mentioned there somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the [link to the Financial Consumer Agency of Canada](http://www.fcac-acfc.gc.ca/eng/resources/publications/creditLoans/Pages/Shopping-Choisirl.aspx#How), @ChrisW.Rea. It explained in clear terms that I can withdraw money from and transfer money to the line of credit any time I want. The only monthly payment needed is the minimum payment. And yes, it may have a term after which all remaining principal + interest must be paid back in full.

> Similar to a credit card, as you pay off your line of credit, you can
>   draw on it again, up to the limit you are allowed. However, a key
>   difference between a line of credit and a credit card is that with a
>   line of credit there is no interest-free grace period. You will have
>   to pay interest on the amount you borrow from the day you take the
>   money out.
>
> You will receive a monthly statement that shows the amount that you
>   owe on your line of credit. **You must make at least a minimum payment
>   on that balance every month**.

(n.b. Specific terms and conditions for lines of credit vary from institution to institution.)